# How to uninitialise CUDA?

Tags: cuda, initialization, gpgpu

CUDA implicitly initialises when the first CUDA runtime function is called.

I'm timing the runtime of my code and repeating 100 times via a loop (`for([100 times]) {[Time CUDA code and log]}`), which also needs to take into account the initialisation time for CUDA at each iteration. Thus I need to uninitialise CUDA after every iteration - how to do this?

I've tried using `cudaDeviceReset()`, but seems not to have uninitialised CUDA.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to include the initialization time in the loop?

Comment: As that would reflect most accurately the complete execution time of my code

Comment: If your program runs so briefly that the CUDA initialization time becomes a factor, then you probably have a lot of overhead in starting the program repeatedly. It would then be better to do more work each time the program is started. You might also consider implementing it as a service.

Comment: If you really want to include initialization and-the-kitchen-sink in your measurement, you could time your whole application. For example use `time` in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cudaDeviceReset` is the canonical way to *destroy a context* in the runtime API (and calling `cudaFree(0)` is the canonical way to create a context). Those are the only levels of "re-initialization" available to a running process. There are other *per-process* events which happen when a process loads the CUDA driver and runtime libraries and connects to the kernel driver, but there is no way I am aware of to make those happen programatically short of forking a new process.

But I really doubt you want or should be needing to account for this sort of setup time when calculating performance metrics anyway.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to uninitialize the driver proper, but it does not take up a significant amount of resource in any case.  Almost all of the data structures it initializes are statically allocated, with the possible exception of the device properties.